# How to populate xamarin collection view with data from http request?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make a collection view with data I get with a http get request. I have a simple model:

```
public class Announce
{
        public int AnnounceId { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
}
```

a Service with following method to get a list of announces that works fine and returns the list of announces.

```
 public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<List<Announce>> GetAnnouncesAsync ()
        {
            List<Announce> announces = new List<Announce>();
            using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
            {
                httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", SecureStorage.GetAsync("key").Result);
                var url = "http://10.0.2.2:51713/api/announces";
                var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Announce>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);               
                announces = result;
            }           
            return announces;
        }
```

Then I have a simple Xamarin page with a Collection View with Binding

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:App1.ViewModels"
             x:Class="App1.Pages.BrowsingPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:AnnouncesViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Announces}">
           //template
        </CollectionView>
    </ContentPage.Content>    
</ContentPage>
```

And the AnnouncesViewModel that should supply my BrowsingPage with data gotten from the Service.

```
public class AnnouncesViewModel
{
    public List<Announce> Announces { get; set; }
       
    public AnnouncesViewModel()
    {
        Announces = new AnnouncesService().GetAnnouncesAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

My application is getting stuck in the `AnnouncesService` waiting for client response. What is the good way to assign data from the service to Announces knowing that GetAnnouncesAsync is an async method and should probably be awaited in AnnouncesViewModel but it's not possible to do in the constructor?

Comment: You could init it before get data `Announces = new List<Announce>();`

Comment: you're causing a deadlock by using Result on async methods.  Don't do that

Comment: Yes that's what I have noticed but I don't know how to get the data otherwise. That's why I'm asking how to bind that data.

Comment: @Ecuros use async await

Comment: But I can't use it in the constructor, that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix some things in your code:

1. For the deadlock you can use this workaround
2. You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged
3. Check if the api is working correctly

```
public class AnnouncesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
     
    private ObservableCollection<Announce> announces
    public ObservableCollection<Announce> Announces { 
        get => announces; 
        set {
            announces= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Announces");
        } 
    }

    public AnnouncesViewModel()
    {
        LoadAnnounces();
    }

    
    private async void LoadAnnounces(){
        Announces = new ObservableCollection<Announce>();
        Announces = await new AnnouncesService().GetAnnouncesAsync();
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
         if (PropertyChanged != null)
         {
             PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also needed to call OnPropertyChanged in LoadAnnounces and it worked!